# What's the return type of std::ranges::max_element?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I wrote the following expression:

```
//definition and initialization
std::map<int ,double> my_map;
my_map[1]=2.0;
my_map[2]=3.0;
```

And then I wanted to find the max_element through the function `std::ranges::max_element` with range adaptors(for study)

```
auto result{std::ranges::max_element(my_map|take(2))};
```

After getting the result, I tried to use "->" to get the first value of the pair of value contain in the iterator `result`

`result->first;//I think (*result) will get a pair.In this example, it will be {2,3.0}`

However the compiler pointed out the error that `No viable overloaded 'operator->'`

And I found that the type of `result` is *`counted_iterator<...>` *

But when I tested

```
std::vector<int> my_vector{1,2,3};
auto max_number{std::ranges::max_element(my_vector|take(3))};
```

I could use `*max_number`  to get the max integer 3 in the vector.

And I found that the type of `max_number` is *`__normal_iterator<...>` *

I am confusing with the iterator type returned by `std::ranges::max_element` which determine when I can use the operator `->` .

I sincerely appreciate your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterator type of `take_view` will [vary depending on how refined the underlying range is](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.take.view).

When the underlying range is `std::map`, `take_view`'s `begin()` will return a `counted_iterator` that records the correct size because we can calculate it through `std::min(my_map.size(), n)`. Since `counted_iterator` only provides `operator->()` if the underlying iterator is a `contiguous_iterator`, which `map::iterator` clearly is not, you cannot apply `operator->()` to it.

When the underlying range is `std::vector` that satisfies `sized_range` and `random_access_range`, `take_view`'s `begin()` and `end()` will *optimally* return `my_vector.begin()` and `my_vector.begin() + size()` to reduce template instantiation, which is the iterator of the original vector, which is`__normal_iterator` in libstdc++.

`ranges::max_element` returns the iterator of the origin range pointing to the max element, so in your example, it will return `counted_iterator` and `vector::iterator` respectively, which is the result you observed.

If you want to get the max element directly instead of an iterator, you can use `ranges::max`:

```
std::vector<int> my_vector{1,2,3};
auto max = std::ranges::max(my_vector | std::views::take(2));
std::cout << max << "\n"; // 2
```

Comment: But why does `counted_iterator` not have `->`? From the quick look at cppreference, it's supposed to mimic base iterator?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `counted_iterator` only provides `operator->()` if the underlying iterator is a `contiguous_iterator`.

Comment: Hmm. Any idea why it is like this? Can't they just return the underlying iterator by value, or something?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `counted_iterator` did not have `operator->()` before [P2259](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2259r1.html), I believe the reason `P2259` provided it was to work with `std::to_address`.